# Hi! I have an issue in parameter as Data type integer is Boolean which has Override default:

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

In the Holdings report parameter, I have an cash and Accruals option and by default it is showing as 'Override Default' hence, I have updated as false and applied but while re-deploying the Holding Rdl in Visual Studio it was not showing the updated value as False.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameter values do not update on subsequent deployments.

You could delete the report from the report folder and redeploy it, but you'd lose the history, subscriptions and user favourites.

I'd just update the default parameter value manually in the settings of the deployed report.